# Double quotes on AngularJS Highcharts data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, highcharts

I am using AngularJS Highcharts with data from a web service call, and `DataStore` variable holds my original data while the one quoted is after JSON conversion, though I don't know how Highcharts get this data from the controller.

```
DataStore =  [[04/10/2015,534.827468425035],[04/10/2015,213.072995232185]];
DataStore_After_JSON_Conversion = "[[04/10/2015,534.827468425035],[04/10/2015,213.072995232185]]"
```

Consider the following fiddle, where I added double quotes on the data and it doesn't work, in the chart config section.
http://jsfiddle.net/yishagerew/4s1u219r/
and here is the working version with no double quotes. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/
I used `String.replace` like `dataStore.replace(expr)` and everything so to remove the quotes but it will add **anyway** when it generates the JSON format.
Would you please help me on how to remove this quotes during which it generates JSON file from angular scope variable?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't really understand what is your problem. I saw your fiddle, I can't see any container for the graph(html). You didn't import the highcharts library, I can't see where you need help. Could you be clear and update your fiddle so we can focus on your problem, thx...

Comment: The html is part of a big project, which I couldn't provide,even the AngularJS controller. But the problem is clear. When I call highcharts configuration file from the controller in the View, it add double quote over the whole configuration file. Highcharts doesn't work if we add double quotes over the Json conf. file. Let me know if still not clear.

Comment: I think I understand your problem. Problem seems to be in your controler, not in the higcharts plugin.
Did you tried to add the replace function in the following line: `data : DataStore.replace('"','',)` ?

Comment: I did the replace, and I proved that DataStore is clean. No quote when I provide it to the conf file. It is just added in the highcharts plugin. @IsraGab do you know how the plugin works? thanks.

Comment: Never use this plugin

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific about what you're doing and how. Your fiddle contains no information or code that demonstrates the problem. Converting an array to JSON will double quote it. That's a characteristic of the JSON format, and not a Highcharts issue.

Comment: @jlbriggs , that is my problem. The conversion double quotes the data. And if you pass data: "Data_Items", into highcharts, it ignores as if there is no data set. If I remove the quotes manually and tried , it works fine. I really need a way to avoid double quoting the data. Consider the following fiddle, where I added double quotes in the existing data and it doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/yishagerew/4s1u219r/

Comment: @Yishagerew You could `JSON.parse` it - http://jsfiddle.net/4s1u219r/1/

Comment: it Works, thanks @KacperMadej